# Employee's educational background in table using telerik

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I am working on a report using telerik where I want to display employee details along with the educational background.

When I use the only table in the detail section to display the employee educational details it shows alright like university and then college or however I specify but when I use textboxs above the table to show the name, fathername, phone for employee it shows the record on 2 pages one for university and then for college though it should move to the second page only when employee is other than this one.

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody is facing the same problem then I have found out my way by putting the table in detail section and all the other details in header group, then by opening the group properties I have set the Behavior GroupKeepingTogether to "FirstDetail" and did grouping with ID of the employee in my case.
Worked like a charm.